# Too many opened files ubuntu tree command simulation

Tags: c, ubuntu, tree, simulation

Too many opened Files?Well it does open what i want (at least i think so), the problem is I get an infinite loop and too many opened files error comes out of it, a little help please, or a pointer where i got it wrong?(with "," included!)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pwd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
int listdir(const char *nf);
int fileinfo(const char *nf,const char *da){
  struct stat s; struct passwd *pp;
  if(stat(nf,&s)==-1)return -1;
  if((pp=getpwuid(s.st_uid))==NULL)return -1;
  if((s.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR) listdir(da);
  printf(" %s\n",nf);
  return 0;
}
int listdir(const char *nf){
 DIR *pd; struct dirent *pde;
 char cale[256], specificator[256]; 
 char cale2[256];
 if((pd=opendir(nf))==NULL)return -1;
 strcpy(cale2,nf);
 strcpy(cale, nf); strcat(cale,"/");
 while((pde=readdir(pd))!=NULL){
   strcpy(specificator, cale); strcat(specificator, pde->d_name);
   if(fileinfo(specificator,cale2)==-1)perror(specificator);
 }
 return 0;
}
int main(int na, char *a[]){
  if(na==2)if(listdir(a[1])==-1)perror(a[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be generous and affort yourself (and us the readers) some line-breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that there are `..`(parent directory) and `.`(current directory) in the results of `readdir`. You shall prevent your recursive `listdir()` call on these two entries.
Also you need to call `closedir` when finished using it.

Below is a quick fix of your function `listdir`:

```
int listdir(const char *nf){
    DIR *pd; struct dirent *pde;
    char cale[256], specificator[256]; 
    char cale2[256];
    if((pd=opendir(nf))==NULL)return -1;
    strcpy(cale2,nf);
    strcpy(cale, nf); strcat(cale,"/");
    while((pde=readdir(pd))!=NULL){
         if (!strcmp(pde->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(pde->d_name, ".."))
             continue;
         strcpy(specificator, cale); strcat(specificator, pde->d_name);
         if(fileinfo(specificator,cale2)==-1)perror(specificator);
    }
    closedir(pd);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, please notice that there's no grantee the combined path name in `calce/calce2/specificator` would be less than 256 bytes -- 256  is only typically the maximum length of `d_name` in a `struct dirent`.

Comment: yes you are right thank you very much, however my implementation is just shit, it doesn't do what I intended it to do  , time for a fresh start. Love you <3(no homo)

Comment: @LucianTarna Two things to remind you: 1. it's not shit but precious as long as you write it (love it) with your heart and soul, 2. every single Ace Programmer once wrote shit code while growing up. :D Cheers!